# add data to listview when clicked flutter

Tags: api, flutter, listview

I have a listview in my app. When I click on the items if item have any data , I want the show company name and and if there is no data I want to save the selected one and move to the next page. If there is data I want open my card and show it as a list. (On the same page)
How can I get it to open the card according to the company name? Is it possible to add new widgets in Ontap?

Here is my code,

```
class _CountryScreenState extends State<CountryScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12.0),
            child: Text('Please chose',style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 16),),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: FutureBuilder<CountryList>(
                future: fetchCountryList(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<CountryList> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
                        return Container(
                          height: 72,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child: Card(
                            child: InkWell(
                              onTap: () async {
                                List<Company> companies= await fetchCompaniesList(snapshot.data.data[position].code);
                                Navigator.pushNamed(context, MainScreen.routeName);

                              },
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding:
                                        const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                                    child: Image.asset(
                                      'icons/flags/png/${snapshot.data.data[position].code.toLowerCase()}.png',
                                      package: 'country_icons',
                                      height: 20,
                                      width: 34,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding:
                                        const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                                    child: Text(snapshot.data.data[position].name,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  } else {
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add the widgets on tap, you can directly add a document to firebase, and use a StreamBuilder instead of a FutureBuilder.

Can you add details to when you want to expand the card ?

Comment: Of course, if I have any company names, I want  drop down my card widget and list company names. Then  user choose one of these company names and navigate new page

Comment: What will change if I using streambuilder?

Comment: If you use a streambuilder, then when you add new objects to firebase (onTap) it will directly be in your app so it can add cards on Tap.

Comment: For the dropdown part, I would use a Future Builder now, and add it on Top of the Container or the Card , that would fetch the list of companies, so that you could use it build the card with all the companies, and have your expanded card built

Comment: You say If I am going to use streambuilder, I need to add FutureBuilder to it?(because of my dropdown part?) I don't fully understand the solution:/

Comment: No, First : 
Use the stream builder instead of the current Future Builder you're using. That way, when you add new elements to firestore on tap, you will directly see them appear.

Then, Within this Stream Builder, If you to get the drop down effect you want, go with a FutureBuilder that performs this ```fetchCompaniesList(snapshot.data.data[position].code)```
so that you have all the data you need to build you expanded card

Comment: didn't work when I converted it to streambuilder, the data didn't come and it should be future:( I tried to create an if else state in onTap to create futurebuilder but even if I say (companies == null) it accepts all of them as  not null.